# How to get doctrine2 entity one to many entities that are set "active"

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

Let's assume there is a OneToMany doctrine2 association between blogposts and comments. A blogposts might have many comments. Every comment remains inactive and therefore hidden in the frontend until a moderator will activate the comment manually.

I'm now trying to have some kind of security facade to ensure that only "active" comments will be provided to the view by accessing them in a loop over the {{blogpost.comments}} variable in the twig template.

Trying to use the getComments() method in the blogpost entity I was trying to filter the ArrayCollection of comments like so

```
/**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getComments()
{
    return $this->comments->filter(function ($condition) {
        return $condition->getActive() === true;
    });
}
```

unfortunately Doctrine will entirely load every single comment even if the relations fetch mode is set to "EXTRA_LAZY". So that would influence the performance of an application in a way i'd like to avoid.

Is there any way to hide the inactive comments globally or do I have to take care of filtering them every time I'm accessing the blogpost.comments relations in the view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `matching` method of your collection. If your collection is not loaded, it will add filters to the SQL query to only load what you need. If your collection is already loaded, it will filter the PHP array.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;

public function getComments()
{
    return $this->comments->matching(
        Criteria::create()->where(
            Criteria::expr()->eq('active', true)
        )
    );
}
```

More informations here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections

Regards

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for! Thank you very much!